# Tor on my network's firewall?

Tags: network-configuration

Can I run Tor on a firewall sitting between my home network and my ISP and essentially force all internet traffic to/from my house through Tor? Ignoring of course that some applications still will leak identifying information, would this technically work? If some applications would still see my Tor firewall's external IP address as my PC's "real" address, could I then put my Tor firewall behind yet another firewall like this:

PC <--------------> Tor Firewall <-----------------> Y.A.Firewall <----------> ISP/internet

10.0.0.2........10.0.0.1...192.168.0.2.......192.168.0.1...W.X.Y.Z

and have programs on my PC think my "real" IP address was 192.168.0.2 instead of W.X.Y.Z?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I see now I want an Isolating Proxy (https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/IsolatingProxy). I've been looking through the documentation and wiki and didn't find it. Looking through posts here with the network-configuration tag did the trick. Sorry to be a bother, but perhaps someone else can find this and quickly get the answer. And apparently the "Yet another firewall" isn't necessary.